# passing file as a http request in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

Right now I am passing the XML file directly. But I want it to be passed as a httpRequest as shown in the below comment

```
// String xmlRequest = getXMLRequest(httpRequest);
   String xmlRequest = tdFile.fileToString("C:/Users/praneel/Desktop/file.xml");
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean they'll pass the path to the file on their system or do you mean something else?

Comment: What is this question about? a) Reading a file to a string / byte array or b) creating a POST request with an attached file or c) both? What technology are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I really have to guess what you mean, but if this is about handling uploaded files on the server side, take a look at [Commons/Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

If you mean sending file contents to a HTTP Server, then [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) may be the right choice for you. See [Code Examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)